# Image of an absolute value function

Tags: absolute-value, formal-proofs

I need to find the image in regards to this question.

> What is the image of the function $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
>
> $f(x) = \frac{|x+3|}{|x|+3}$?

What I tried to do is to set $y =$ to $f(x)$ and then get $x$:

Let $y = f(x) = \frac{|x+3|}{|x|+3}$

$y = \frac{|x+3|}{|x|+3}$

$y(|x|+3) = |x+3|$

I don't know how to go from here as I don't know what to do/how to get rid of the absolute value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|x+3|\ge0$ and $|x|+3>0$, so $f(x)\ge0$.

$|x+3|\le |x|+3$, so $f(x)\le1$.

$f(-3)=0$ and $f(0)=1$, and $f$ is continuous.

So the image is $[0,1]$.

Comment: How does line 2 imply that f(x) less than or equal to 1?

Comment: Since $|x|+3$ is positive, you may divide both sides of an inequality by it

Comment: OK got it thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

** Hint:** Note that $x=-3$ and $x=0$ are the places where something “important” happens to the absolute value expressions. Everywhere in between and beyond, you can replace a symbol like $|u|$ with either $u$ or $-u$, whichever makes the expression $u$ nonnegative.

So consider the cases $x\leq -3$, $-3<x\leq 0$, and $x>0$ separately.

Comment: Isn't it $-3<x<0$ and $x\geq 0$ instead?

Comment: It’s the same since this function is continuous everywhere. At the transition point, the thing that is changing is zero. In other words, if $|u|=0$, then both $|u|=u$ and $|u|=-u$ are true. So you can just use strict inequality everywhere if you want and consider all the transition points separately, as long as you eventually consider them somewhere @RingØ

Comment: It's the same at $0$ but you were saying "*places where something important happens*", and it seems more logical to me to put the negatives on one side, and $\geq 0$ on the other, while that doesn't change the result mathematically.

Comment: @RingØ : There are intervals $(-\infty,-3)$, $(-3,0)$, $(0,\infty)$ and there are boundary points $-3$,$0$. By continuity, the boundary points can be included in any or all of the intervals. There is no “natural” place for them. I just chose to consistently use half-open intervals $(a,b]$ where possible.